# Access data of fusion table in Google drive under service account

Tags: google-maps, google-drive-api, google-fusion-tables

When i am trying to insert permission to fusion table in my service with group it works fine but i am not to access the same table in my map application where i am using fusion layer API

```
insertPermission(drive, tableid, "XXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com","group", "writer");
```

But when i try same piece of code to insert permission with anyone i get response back with 500 (internal server error )

```
insertPermission(drive, tableid, "XXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com","anyone", "writer");
```

I prime aim is to use the data in the fusion table in my service account in my Map application .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have write permission with anyone to access .I tried with 
**insertPermission(drive, tableid, "XXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com","anyone", "reader");**
and it worked fine with me and i was able to populate that in the map as well.